# Green Quiz attempt

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quiz as part of my assignment. I was thinking of doing a percentage of how green or mean someone's answers are and calculating it.  I plan to use a Dictionary and a loop. I also thought of opening a file to post some random facts after each question. But that last part is irrelevant. For now, there is something wrong with my coding. I thought a For Loop is supposed to scan every item in a list or dictionary but it keeps stopping short. It only registers one question at a time before skipping over to the calculation part. What is the problem with my coding?

These are my functions for calculating the percentage of answers.

```
def Green():
    green_score=float(green_point/question_num)
    if green_score >=0 and green_score <=2:
        print("Do you even know what green means besides the color?")
    if green_score >=3 and green_score <=4:
        print("Slightly green but a lot more can help.")
    if green_score >=5 and green_score <=6:
        print("Half and half, aren't cha?")
    if green_score > 7 and green_score <=8:
        print("I have a life and I want to paint it green.")
    if green_score >=9 and green_score <=10:
        print("Green thumbs all around!")
    print(green_score)

def Mean():
    mean_score=float(mean_point/question_num)
    if mean_score >=0 and mean_score <=2:
        print("No black thumbs here!")
    if mean_score >=3 and mean_score <=4:
        print("Not so Green but not so mean either.")
    if mean_score >=5 and mean_score <=6:
        print("Not half-bad but not half-good either.")
    if mean_score >=7 and mean_score <=8:
       print("Are you going out of your way to hurt Planet Earth?")
    if mean_score >=9 and mean_score <=10:
        print("Welp, there won't be a planet to live in if there are more people like you.")
    print (mean_score)
```

This is my dictionary.

```
QUESTIONS={("%7s" % "\v What do you prefer for your meals? \n a. cooking at home or b. fast food ","a"),
("%7s" % "\v How do you prefer to travel? \n car or bike?","bike"),
("%7s" % "\v What bags do you prefer to carry groceries? \n plastic or paper?","paper"),
("%7s" % "\v What do you do with your waste? \n trash or recycle?","recycle"),
    ("%7s" % "\v How do you get your power? \n Do you rely on a. fossil fuel or b. renewable energy?","b" ),
    ("%7s" % "\v What kind of hobbies do you enjoy? \n do you prefer gardening or television?","gardening"),
    ("%7s" % "\v Where do you want to go for your vacation? \n a. to an amusement park? or b. to a nature spot such as a mountain or lake.","b"),
    ("%7s" % "\v Do you believe companies such as Coca-Cola, Windex, and Shell about promoting sustainable activities such as using ocean plastic in their products? \n true or false?","false"),
    ("%7s" % "\v Where do you get your clothing from? \n a. Fast fashion which are trendy outfits mass-produced to be worn or thrown away. or b. clothing brands that promote sustainable activities reducing the environmental impact?", "b"),
    ("%7s" % "\v some electronics are running in your house when not in use such as lights, washing machine, and oven. \n Do you turn them on or off?","off")}
```

This is the for loop that would initiate the quiz.

```
for question, correct_answer in QUESTIONS:
    answer = input(f"{question} ").lower()
    time.sleep(1)
    if answer == correct_answer:
        print("Green!")
        green_point+=1
        question_num
        print(green_facts[random.randint(0,46)])
    else:
        print("Mean!")
        print(green_facts[random.randint(0,46)])
        mean_point+=1
        question_num+=1
    
        print("\vWell done with the quiz. Let's see how well you did.")
   
        Green()
        Mean()
```

Let me know as soon as possible if you found anything? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem is your calculations are called *inside* the loop instead of after it…‽

Comment: Couple of things not related to your problem: `QUESTIONS` is not `dict` but `set` of `tuples`. And why do you define the first element in each typle with old-style string formatting (using `"%7s" %`) ? Also what do you think this line is doing in the `if` block `question_num`

Answer (score 1):

```
def Green(score):
    if score in range(0, 3):
        print("Do you even know what green means besides the color?")
    if score in range(3, 5):
        print("Slightly green but a lot more can help.")
    if score in range(5, 7):
        print("Half and half, aren't cha?")
    if score in range(7, 9):
        print("I have a life and I want to paint it green.")
    if score in range(9, 11):
        print("Green thumbs all around!")
    print(score)
```

```
def Mean(score):
    if score in range(0, 3):
        print("No black thumbs here!")
    if score in range(3, 5):
        print("Not so Green but not so mean either.")
    if score in range(5, 7):
        print("Not half-bad but not half-good either.")
    if score in range(7, 9):
       print("Are you going out of your way to hurt Planet Earth?")
    if score in range(9, 11):
        print("Welp, there won't be a planet to live in if there are more people like you.")
    print(score)
```

```
QUESTIONS={("%7s" % "\v What do you prefer for your meals? \n a. cooking at home or b. fast food ","a"),
           ("%7s" % "\v How do you prefer to travel? \n car or bike?","bike"),
           ("%7s" % "\v What bags do you prefer to carry groceries? \n plastic or paper?","paper"),
           ("%7s" % "\v What do you do with your waste? \n trash or recycle?","recycle"),
           ("%7s" % "\v How do you get your power? \n Do you rely on a. fossil fuel or b. renewable energy?","b" ),
           ("%7s" % "\v What kind of hobbies do you enjoy? \n do you prefer gardening or television?","gardening"),
           ("%7s" % "\v Where do you want to go for your vacation? \n a. to an amusement park? or b. to a nature spot such as a mountain or lake.","b"),
           ("%7s" % "\v Do you believe companies such as Coca-Cola, Windex, and Shell about promoting sustainable activities such as using ocean plastic in their products? \n true or false?","false"),
           ("%7s" % "\v Where do you get your clothing from? \n a. Fast fashion which are trendy outfits mass-produced to be worn or thrown away. or b. clothing brands that promote sustainable activities reducing the environmental impact?", "b"),
           ("%7s" % "\v some electronics are running in your house when not in use such as lights, washing machine, and oven. \n Do you turn them on or off?","off")}
```

```
green_point = mean_point = 0

for question, correct_answer in QUESTIONS:
    answer = input(f"{question} ").lower()
    if answer == correct_answer:
        print("Green!")
        green_point += 1
    else:
        print("Mean!")
        mean_point += 1
    #print(green_facts[random.randint(0,46)])
        
    
print("\vWell done with the quiz. Let's see how well you did.")
Green(green_point)
Mean(mean_point)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please condense your code to show the single error you're having :)

### What you have isn't a dictionary; it's a set of tuples. A dictionary has `key : pair` values, and I believe this is what you're going for.

Your current "dictionary" (really a set-type) is arranged:

`{(key, value), (key, value)}`

In simple terms, you have a list of lists.

A dictionary should be arranged like:

`{key:value, key:value}`

The key (pun intended) difference is the use of a colon to differentiate keys from values, rather than using indexes in tuples.

Comment: Even if it's not a dict, OP's usage of it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @deceze sure, but they explicitly state that they are trying to use a dictionary.